# Who is Julius Kingsley?

Tags: code-geass, code-geass-akito-the-exiled

In the second episode of "Code Geass: Akito the Exiled" a man calling himself "Julius Kingsley" exites a train of the royal family. To understand this episode and not getting spoiled by my question you should have seen Code Geass R1 completely, the beginning of Code Geass R2 and the first episode of "Code Geass: Akito the exiled".

(Note that "Code Geass: Akito the Exiled" takes place in the year beetween Code Geass R1 and Code Geass R2)

> The man exiting the train looks like Lelouch, his behaviour is also similar to Lelouch's (except Lelouch is less arrogant). The facts that Suzaku accompanies him and he wears an eyepatch on his left eye (the source of Lelouch's Geass) made me think whether this really is Lelouch or not. My first thought was that Lelouch lost his memories of the time before he was send to Japan (maybe he lost more memories too) and sees himself as a member of the royal family. Also, Julius Kingsley takes complete control of the troup planing. As Lelouch is a great tactician, I came to the conclusion that Julius Kingsley has to be Lelouch. Am I right? If so, why does he call himself Julius Kingsley? And what happened in the train, when he desperately begged for water?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you mean `Julius`? Also, quick google turned up this [**wiki page**](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Julius_Kingsley)

Comment: @kei You're completely right. I don't know how I ended up with `Alexander`. The wiki page you found does not really answer my question. Most of the similarities beetween Julius and Lelouch are mentioned there, but there is no clear answer whether Lelouch is Julius or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In episode 3 of the OVA series it's revealed that Julius Kingsley is infact a brainwashed Lelouch. the brainwashing however is somewhat unstable as when Julius is seen on the train cluching his eye this is a sign that the brainwashing hasn't fully worked and "Lelouch" is trying to come back. he reappears briefly later on showing also that his Geass has yet to be sealed as it is at the start of R2

> [image: Lelouch Reappeaering]

Comment: That's a good theory. Julius being a clone of Lelouch made by the order would make sense. Although this would raise some additional questions like "Can two clones be that similar? How much is destined by genetics?". We cannot give a clear answer to that, so we should consider Julius being Lelouch. Making two memory alterations should not be more difficult than one and they really look alike. (The differences you mentioned probably are the result of the never production. I noticed several light changes)

Comment: @Sirac with the memory alterations, firstly we're not exactly sure how they were done (drugs, technology, etc.). i'm assuming Charles Geass because when Shirley was affected by the Geass Canceler she not only remember Lelouch as Zero (Lelouch's Geass) but she also remembered Nunnally is Lelouch's sibling, not Rolo. the Canceler only removed Lelouch's Geass then she wouldn't have remembered Nunnally's role in Lelouch's life (his order was to To forget Lelouch)

Comment: (cont) now given that, when Lelouch first enters the Sword of Akasha Charles still has control of his Geass which means he hasn't used it enough for it to go out of control and in my opinion had Charles did 2 memory alterations his Geass would have went out of control. ofcause all of this is speculation, Akito of the Exiled i'm hoping answers the question raised by the time gap, most importantly, how did C.C survive without Free Pizza from Lelouch

Comment: This is the most acceptable answer since Akito the Exiled is an OVA of season 1. Since that OVA fills in the gap beteeen season 1 and 2. And we see how Emperor Charles used Lelouch for his needs in leading the EU Brittania forces in that 1 year gap between season 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

It is widely believed that Julius is in fact Lelouch. He bares a striking resemblance to Lelouch, wears an eye patch to cover his Geass, and he is a master tactician. Unfortunately, no official information is out yet because ep 3 is still in production but it is assumed that when Suzaku brought Lelouch before Emperor Charles, Charles used his Geass to alter Lelouch's memories temporarily so that he thought that he was a Britannian tactician.
The water part still has not been explained, at least not that I know of. It possably was just a technique used by the writers too show Lelouch's current interactions with Suzaku and how they feel towards each other but that is just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Lelouch's entry in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lelouch_Lamperouge), Julius Kingsley is **Zero (Lelouch)**.

> **Akito The Exiled**
>
> After Suzaku brings Lelouch to Charles, he offers to hand him over on the condition he be inducted into the Knights of the Round, much to Lelouch's dismay. Charles agrees, and uses his Geass to alter Lelouch's mind. With this, Lelouch becomes the empire's slave, Julius Kingsley, wearing an eyepatch over his Geass.
>
> Lelouch makes a few appearances in the miniseries, first seen in Suzaku's custody as **he clutches his right eye while begging his friend for water, only to be silently turned down**. In his second appearance upon arriving in St. Petersburg, Kingsley proudly declares that the Emperor has placed him in charge of all the Eastern front operational planning for Britannia's military.
>
> In the third episode, Lelouch encounters Shin Hyuga Shaing and others for a meeting. In which he tries to arrest the others in his plan. **Lelouch showcases a clip to create fear and havoc within the city**. Later on, he plays chess along Hyuga, but starts hallucinating Kingsley and past memories from Rebellion. Later on **Hyuga figures out that he was both Zero and Lelouch** and calls his squad. **Suzaku, in an attempt to defend the secret, kills most of the squad whilst Lelouch rips off his eye-patch**. Eventually, both are captured, with Hyuga later declaring Kingsley executed and **revealing that he is Zero**.

This entry summarizes the episodes in *Akito The Exiled* where Julius Kingsley (Zero) is seen.

Also, Lelouch's character profile includes Julius Kingsley as one of his **aliases**.

> > **Nickname(s)**
>
> Lulu, The Black Prince
>
> > **Aliases**
>
> Lelouch Lamperouge
>
> Zero
>
> ***Julius Kingsley***
>
> > **Title**
>
> 11th Prince of Britannia
>
> 99th Emperor of Britannia
>
> > **Relatives**
>
> Charles zi Britannia (father)
>
> Marianne vi Britannia (mother)
>
> Nunnally vi Britannia (sister)
>
> Rolo Lamperouge (adopted brother)
>
> Clara Lamperouge (adopted sister)
>
> > **Nationality**
>
> Britannian

With the third episode revealed, it is stated that Zero and Kingsley are the same person, and he is but a brainwashed Lelouch serving the Emperor of Britannia.

According to [Julius Kingsley's entry](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Julius_Kingsley) in Code Geass Wikia,

> A young man with a striking resemblance to Lelouch vi Britannia whose left eye is covered with an eye-patch for unknown reasons.

[image: Julius Kingsley]

> In episode 3 of Akito the Exiled, Julius was **revealed to indeed be a brainwashed Lelouch** who is completely loyal to the Emperor of Britannia. His eye-patch hides his Geass. There are multiple scenes throughout the OVA series that suggest his state is relatively unstable, with his original personality briefly resurfacing, as indicated by **Kingsley muttering Nunnally's name**, and even going so far as to **calling Julius Kingsley another being all together**.

Answer (score 0):

Jun Fukuyama voices both Lelouch and Julius. As for the clone theory, I expect it might be morally wrong to clone people, the same as it is in the real world. Charles could have changed Lelouch's memories multiple times too. As for the unnamed child's geass, according to the wiki, it was most likely given to him by V.V.

Answer (score 0):

Julius Kingsley is really in fact Lelouch because Xin Hyuga Shaing also suspect it and Suzaku says "He is Zero" . And there is also a pic that Julius Kingsley is really in fact Lelouch [enter link description here](https://vk.com/photo278017489_366517888)

Comment: **Lord Shaing** was the one who said "_He is Zero_" not Suzaku

Answer (score 0):

Julius is actually Lelouch. In the 3rd OVA, his memories has been rewritten and brainwashed. His eye that was covered was actually infact a Geass. While Shinn, says to Suzaku that his purpose was just like his, it is heard that he said Nunnally, also fragments of his memories started to Return with Charles Rewriting his memory. This Confirms he is actually Lelouch.

Answer (score 0):

In my belief this is Lelouch but brainwashed from his precious memory's like Nunnally and more and rewriten as a tactician for the royal family Julius has an amazing resemblance to lelouch and exclusively during the fight between Suzaku and Xin Hyuga Shaing Suzaku admits it and as thefightgoes on Julius " Lelouch " gets bad and start remembering thing and especially on wikipedia it explains that he was in akito the exiled